# Unit test custom doctrine repository

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, doctrine, phpunit, repository

I have a custom entity repository. For example, it looks like this:

```
namespace Foo\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class Article extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findRecent($limit)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
        $qb->andWhere('a.publishDate IS NOT NULL')
           ->orderBy('a.publishDate', 'DESC')
           ->setMaxResults($limit);

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

I want to test in this case:

1. There is an ORDER BY in "recent"
2. There is a limit
3. The entity must have a publish date

I **do not** want to validate the SQL output of the query builder, since Doctrine can change the SQL between different versions. That will break my unit test. Therefore, my idea was this:

1. Create a mock of my repository
2. Create a mock of the query builder
3. Make sure `$this->createQueryBuilder('a')` returns the mocked query builder
4. Test for method calls on the query builder

In code:

```
namespace FooTest\Repository;

use PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase as TestCase;

class ArticleRepositoryTest extends TestCase
{
    protected $qb;
    protected $repository;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->qb         = $this->getMockBuilder('Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder')
                                 ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                                 ->getMock();
        $this->repository = $this->getMockBuilder('Foo\Repository\Article')
                                 ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                                 ->getMock();

        $this->repository->expects($this->once())
                         ->method('createQueryBuilder')
                         ->with($this->equalTo('a'))
                         ->will($this->returnValue($this->qb));
    }

    public function testFindRecentLimitsToGivenLimit()
    {
        $limit = '1';
        $this->qb->expects($this->any())
                 ->method('setMaxResults')
                 ->with($this->equalTo($limit));

        $this->repository->findRecent($limit);
    }

    public function testFindRecentOrdersByPublishDate()
    {
        $this->qb->expects($this->any())
                 ->method('andWhere')
                 ->with($this->equalTo('a.publishDate'), $this->equalTo('DESC'));

        $this->repository->findRecent(1);
    }
}
```

This `findRecent()` call however **never** calls `createQueryBuilder` internally. PhpUnit points out:

> FooTest\Repository\ArticleRepositoryTest::testFindRecentLimitsToGivenLimit
>   Expectation failed for method name is equal to  when invoked 1 time(s).
>   Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.

I think I did something wrong in creating the repository mock. How can I make sure this approach works? Or if there is a better alternative, what is that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are mocking the Repository you are trying to test, so `findRecent()` is indeed mocked and will return null.

You should be able to use the real repository instance.

Comment: I have to mock my own object I test, because it extends a Doctrine repository and the `createQueryBuilder` does more than simply returning a `QueryBullder` object. I have now had help via Twitter to make my repository a partial mock (which works). I now have problems with the chained methods inside the query builder, so unfortunately it's not working yet :-)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found to testing subclassed repositories is to add a call to `setMethodsExcept()` when building the mock.

So you would modify your code within `setUp()` above like so:

```
$this->repository = $this->getMockBuilder('Foo\Repository\Article')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->setMethodsExcept([
        // Insert any overridden/implemented functions here, in your case:
        'findRecent',
    ])
    ->getMock();
```